# Inside type definition is reserved: Defining an array of structures inside another structure

Tags: julia

Julia throws an error when i try to have an array of structures inside another structure.

```
ERROR: LoadError: syntax: "grid = Cell[]" inside type definition is reserved
```

here is the test code i am trying to run.

```
struct Cell
    color::Int64
    location::Int64
    Cell(color::Int64,location::Int64) = new(color,location)
    Cell()=new(0,0)
end

struct Grid
    dimensions::Int64
    timestep::Int64
    grid=Cell[]
    courseGrain=Cell[]
    Grid(dimensions::Int64,timestep::Int64,grid_cell::Cell,courseGrain_cell::Cell) = 
    new(dimensions,timestep,push!(grid,grid_cell),push!(courseGrain,courseGrain_cell))
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining default field values within field declarations is currently not allowed. See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/10146

To achieve what you want, define your `grid` and `courseGrain` as a 1D array of type `Cell`, i.e. `Array{Cell, 1}` or equivalently `Vector{Cell}`, and handle the default case in your constructors.

```
struct Grid
    dimensions::Int64
    timestep::Int64
    grid::Vector{Cell}
    courseGrain::Vector{Cell}
    Grid(dimensions::Int64,timestep::Int64,grid_cell::Cell,courseGrain_cell::Cell) = 
    new(dimensions,timestep,[grid],[courseGrain_cell])
end
```

If you want one of your constructors to create an empty `grid` or `courseGrain`, you may write `Cell[]` or `Vector{Cell}(undef, 0)` in your call to `new`.